# Расчет надежности системы из элементов

Tags: математика

Помогите разобратся с задачей. Система состоит из 7 элементов, надежность каждого элемента 0,75. Для повышения надежности предлагается резервирования по следующей схеме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно определить надежность системы.

Comment: Во-первых, если вам дали такую задачу, значит вас перед этим научили их решать, и сложностей у вас возникнуть не должно. Во-вторых, а при чём тут программирование?

Comment: Надежность нулевая - первый элемент украли! А между 3 и 4 вообще ненадежная нитка :)